# What is named.exe process and how to avoid consuming high CPU rates

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, plesk

I have a Windows Server 2008 with Plesk running two web sites. 
Sometimes the server is going slow and there is a named.exe process making the CPU peak 100%.
It last a short period of time and after a while it comes again.
I would like to know what this process is for and how to configure it for not consuming this cpu and make my sites go slow.

Answer (score 1):

This must be a DNS service, also known as Bind. High CPU usage may indicate one of the following:

1. DNS is re-reading its configuration. In this case high CPU usage shall be aligned with your activities in Plesk - i.e. adding and removing domains.
2. Someone (normally another DNS server) is pulling data from your DNS server. It is normal process. As you say it is for short period of time, it doesn't look like DNS DDoS

AFAIK there is no default way in Windows to restrict software from taking 100% CPU if no other apps require CPU at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

See "DNS Treewalk Suite" system, off the process, and uses the antivirus.

Check the error "log" in the system.

Comment: I cant see DNS Treewalk Suite in my system, i think it is not installed. The folder where named.exe is its "C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\dns\bin" so i think it is something about Plesk?

Comment: is probable that you have conflicts with Microsoft DNS.

Please stop the Microsoft DNS service. It Should resolve the issue.